# curl: (7) Failed connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:80; Connection refused

Tags: ssl, curl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to deploy nginx - ingress

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx

kubectl get pod 
NAME                                       READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-65899c769f-wf7dl                     1/1       Running       0          9m


kubectl expose deploy nginx --port 80
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
nginx        ClusterIP   10.254.75.184      <none>     80/TCP           9m
```

---

```
vi ingress.yml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: kub-mst.coral.io
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: nginx
              servicePort: 80
```

---

```
kubectl get ing
NAME      HOSTS              ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
nginx     kub-mst                      80        9m
```

---

```
vi /etc/hosts
xx.xx.xx.xx  kub-mst.coral.io
```

---

```
curl kub-mst.coral.io
curl: (7) Failed connect to kub-mst; Connection refused
```

I have Kubernetes Cluster and am trying to

```
curl http://xx.xx.xx.xx
```

it returns

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:80; Connection refused
```

and i execute

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

it returns

```
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
KubeDNS is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

xx.xx.xx.xx is public IP.

how to troubleshooting to detect where is the problem

Comment: i guess the problem is that xx.xx.xx.xx does not go to localhost. try `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080 : return result , xx.xx.xx.xx is public IP

Comment: first thing i'd check is if you can receive connections from your global IP at all. have 1 terminal run `nc -l -p 9999`  , then run in another terminal `echo test | nc xx.xx.xx.xx 9999` - did your netcat server receive the connection? (it will print `test` if it did.)

Comment: yes Server receive "test"

Comment: oh cool, then the problem is almost certainly that Kubernets is configured to only accept / listen to localhost connections. reconfigure it to accept connections from anywhere and you should be good to go :)

Comment: Firewall is Stopped

Comment: it's probably not the firewall, it's the server configuration. somewhere it's told to listen to `127.0.0.1:8080` or `localhost:8080`, change it to `0.0.0.0:8080`

Comment: it may be problem of flanneld ?

Comment: Or change 127.0.0.1 localhost to xx.xx.xx.xx localhost in /etc/hosts to avoid this ?

Comment: don't think that'll fix anything. what is the output of `sudo netstat -nNpl`  ?

Comment: i tried export KUBERNETES_MASTER=http://MasterIP:8080
and it fixed 
and Kubernetes master is running at http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
issue here how to fix curl xx.xx.xx.xx:80

Comment: netstat -nNpl  == > Port 80 not one of them

Comment: well you're not looking for port 80, you're looking for port 8080

Comment: okay :
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      13563/kube-apiserve

Comment: What are you trying to do on Kubernetes? Are you talking/curl-ing to a Service?

Comment: iam trying to deploy ingress and nginx on port 80

Comment: How are you trying to deploy them? What have you done some far, was there any guide you were following? Have you setup `Ingress` or specified `Service Type`?

Comment: @Crou https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7K0gAYmWWho

Comment: Please update your question with the `.yaml` files, also provide the output of `kubectl get svc`

Comment: @Crou i edited it , please see again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided the ingress controller with a single rule that matches the **host** header of your request, yet, for some odd reason, you're testing with a request that does not provide the host header.

`curl -H 'Host: kub-mst.coral.io' http://xx.xx.xx.xx`